# Does Workday have any API to put tasks to employee inbox?

Tags: workday-api

I'm looking for a solution to assign a task to the employee through Workday API. Does Workday have any API to put tasks to employee inbox?

Comment: What task are you trying to assign? If it's a Workday Business Process, that setup should be done in the BP.

Comment: @WyattShipman I'm trying to put notification to Workday Inbox

Comment: From what system? @nguyendn

Comment: @WyattShipman from a third-party that has access to Workday API. It seems impossible for now.

Comment: A task in workday or in the third party system? What third party system?  Workday has pre-built connectors for certain ones.

Comment: @WyattShipman for instance, a service A - project management app (just for example)-wants to send a task to an employee inbox. If a Workday Connector can do that then it is good news.

Comment: I don't think this is currently available. A customer has posted an Idea for Workday to look into, but there isn't much traction. You might be able to do some kind of workaround with the REST APIs for Check-ins, but it wouldn't be very straight forward...